# Access custom header information in rest api

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

Is there any way to access custom header information using fosrest? I already added the header data in my client, but i don't know how to get it in my server.

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/batch")
 */
public function getBatchAction(\FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher $paramFetcher){ 

}
```

I don't want to pass this parameter via get or post, it's a permanent value, like code or something, that will be in every request, changing according to the user.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to access it using `Request->headers->get('customHeader')`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrey, i could find this answer:

```
public function getBatchAction(Request $request, \FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher $paramFetcher){           
    return $request->headers->get('customheader');
}
```

Using this namespace: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation